# Application is keep terminated without reason

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing a navigation-base application with 11 buttons on the main page.
If I keep repeating clicking a button and going back to the main page, the application is terminated without any error message.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: 11 buttons? maybe squeeze a few more in?

Comment: lol I can't.. I need those 11 buttons haha :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, if you need to do something over and over again to produce a crash, it's probably a memory leak.

Each time you reproduce an action, you'll leak a small amount of memory, until eventually the device runs out and your application crashes.

Check you're releasing your objects properly.

Comment: Aha, I guess I need to check all codes line by line haha thanx

Answer (score 0):

I guarantee there's a reason.

My guess, given I have no code to go on, is that you're getting your buttons via convenience methods (and therefore working with autoreleased UIButton objects) and then releasing them on `-dealloc`.